# How to use static content in .NET Core from server location?

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, virtual-directory

In my .NET Core web app, I want to upload PDF files and display them later. I want to store these files in a folder outside of the project folder on a Windows 2016 server (eg. C:\files).

At first I thought, I could use a virtual directory pointing to C:\files on the IIS server but it seems like that's not possible in .NET Core anymore.

As per this blog post (https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/ ), one should use UseFileServer() instead. Is it possible to configure UseFileServer with a folder outside of the project?

This is what I've tried:

In my `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new 
PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\servername\C:\folder"),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/Uploads"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
        });
```

For testing, I stored an image inside of the folder and then tried:

```
<img src="/Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

Unfortunately, the image is not being displayed.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the path `\\servername\C:\folder` exist?

Comment: If I see it correctly, is `\\servername\C:\folder` a remote path? Are you sure this path can be accessed in this way? I think you would have to create drive release.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I double checked that it exists..

Comment: @BenjaminJ. The folder is on the hosting server if that's what you we're referring to. Do I need to allow access to a certain user group?

Comment: @Jimmy: What do you mean with `hosting server`. Is the specified path and your .NET Core application on the same server? If yes, why do you want to specify the server name if it's the same server.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. I changed the path as you were right, the Server running the .NET Core app and the specified path are the same. Thanks a lot. If you'd post that as answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks for your offer. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that `\\servername\C:\folder` would expect a directory named `folder` on the share drive `C:` which is located on a remote server with the name `servername`.

But in your case the folder is on the same machine as IIS. So I would only be  `C:\folder`.