# how to access static files from Another server in .net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, middleware, static-files

I have **2 Web Apps** in .Net Core, the first is called '**MiddelwareApp**' that is public To the internet and Receive Requests from clients in encrypted Case Then Decrypt them and sends  Requests to the second App called "**MainApp**" located at another server.

'MainApp'  contains My Controllers In addition to Static Files in WWWRoot.
Sending Requests from MiddlewareApp , mapping to controllers in MainApp, and getting the correct data are done without any problem. ***But the problem with Static Files***
***What I want is to access my static files in MainApp from Middlewareapp in Another server.***

Currently, I am in the local host  **MainApp in port 7000** and **middleware in port 7001**

In program File of mainApp:

```
.........
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//to allow access files in wwwroot without any server-side processing. 
app.UseStaticFiles(new PathString("/app-Assets"));
// to allow access files not in wwwroot
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Assets")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/app-Assets")
});
app.UseRouting();
......
```

I tried In the program file of Middleware app :

```
...
app.UseFileServer(

    new FileServerOptions
    {
        
         FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\https:\\localhost:7000\app-Assets"),

// this is url of  static file in Main app
RequestPath = new PathString("/app-Assets"),
EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
...
```

in my HTML I want to access Image directly from URL of middleware port 7001

```
<img src="https://localhost:7001/app-Assets/myImage.jpg"\>
```

I expected that image src would send request To middleware then 'UseFileServer' in its program
access static file of Main app on another server

The error  say

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: '//https://localhost:7000/app-Assets/'

but if i make path  '{LocalDrive}/app-Assets/' it work

I Follow some guidelines for that but now work for me because

https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/

[How to use static content in .NET Core from server location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699217/how-to-use-static-content-in-net-core-from-server-location)

if some one need some additional details ,I will do

Thanks for your helping

***Edit:* The solution Worked For me**

Using `app.UseFileServer()` method in Middleware App not Work at All ,So I tried another way that make the same effect

```
[Route("GetImage")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string filePath, bool inline = true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

    filePath = Path.Combine("app-Assets\\", filePath);

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("AnotherServerDirectory");
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(filePath);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLowerInvariant();

    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = inline // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
    };

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, GetMimeTypes()[ext]);
}
```

I set **'Content-Disposition'**  to control if I want to download the image or display it directly  from `<img src="">` tag
then in Html I make

```
<img src="https://localhost:700/GetImage?filePath=myImage.jpg"\>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the result, then you can use server to return to the client.

Example:

1. ```html
   <img src="https://localhost:7001/app-Assets?image=myImage.jpg"\>
   ```
2. Stream image from controller's

   ```cs
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("app-Assets")]

   public IActionResult AssetsImage(string image)
   {
       var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead($"app-Assets/{image}");
       return File(image, "image/jpeg");
   }
   ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your solution is similar to what I did, but with some code modification. I have post the solution in an edit of the question. Thank you for your answer